# C# Download File from a network drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have a file that is located at a network drive. The user access is already created to have full access to the path. But it seems that when I ran the following code to get the file, the browser just does not respond.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(GetDocumentUploadFolder(ID) + fileName);

// Checking if file exists
if (file.Exists)
{
    // Clear the content of the response
    this.Page.Response.ClearContent();

    // Clear the header of the response
    this.Page.Response.ClearHeaders();

    // Set the ContentType
    this.Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
    this.Page.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);

    // End the response
    this.Page.Response.End();
}
```

I tried using `this.Page.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);` and it also does not work. The page seems to stop functioning after `this.Page.Response.End();`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? What does happen? When does it stop or throws exception? What is the size of a file?

Comment: The code stops running after `this.Page.Response.End();`. The page only show a blank screen. Size of file is 80KB.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch block around the code in the question?

Comment: Added a try/catch block. It goes to the catch part, the message is : Thread was being aborted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do a workaround by copying the files first from the network drive to local path and then do a TransmitFile from there:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(GetDocumentUploadFolder(ID) + fileName);
string strFolder = Server.MapPath(LocalLocation);
string strDestination = Server.MapPath(LocalLocation + "\\" + fileName);

// Checking if file exists
if (file.Exists)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(strFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolder);
    // Delete contents in this folder
    Common.DeleteFiles(strFolder, "*.*");
    file.CopyTo(strDestination, true);

    // Clear the content of the response
    this.Page.Response.ClearContent();

    // Clear the header of the response
    this.Page.Response.ClearHeaders();

    // Set the ContentType
    this.Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
    this.Page.Response.TransmitFile(strDestination);

    // End the response
    this.Page.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter where file a stored. Your action must return a file as the result:

```
public FileResult GetBytes()
{
   string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/PDFIcon.pdf");
   byte[] mas = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
   string file_type = "application/pdf";
   string file_name = "PDFIcon.pdf";
   return File(mas, file_type, file_name);
}
```

Server.MapPath(filePath string) - must have access to the file.

Comment: I'm not using MVC, so cannot use `FileResult`. Furthermore, `Server.MapPath` will map to physical path, which will not work for remote server.

Comment: Ok. What htp server do you use? Did you try return filepath as a content.

Comment: I'm using ASP .NET Webpage

Comment: String FileName;
 FileStream MyFileStream;
 IntPtr FileHandle;
 long StartPos = 0, FileSize;

 FileName = "c:\\temp\\Login.txt";

 MyFileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open);
 FileHandle = MyFileStream.Handle;
 FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;

 Response.Write("<b>Login: </b>");
 Response.Write("<input type=text id=user /> ");
 Response.Write("<input type=submit value=Submit /><br><br>");

 Response.WriteFile(FileHandle, StartPos, FileSize);

 MyFileStream.Close();

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms150018(v=vs.110).aspx)